# How many keywords is too many?

Tags: seo, html, meta-keywords

> I believe that the question of which this was marked a duplicate seems to be one about the actual HTML tag's max length. I know there is no such max length and instead want to know about how the number of keywords affects SEO

I know that search engines like Google try to detect which webpages are lying by putting in too many keywords in the `<HEAD>`, but what if I have a webpage where very many keywords apply? Specifically, I noted that in my online résumé I have the following tag:

```html
<META NAME="keywords"    CONTENT="Ben Leggiero,Ben,Leggiero,programmer,programming,developer,Java,C,C++,C#,Objective-C,JavaScript,Ruby,Python,HTML5,CSS3,PHP,XML,XSL,Haskell,Lisp,Prolog,COBOL,Android,Android 4.0,Ice Cream Sandwich,Android 4.1,Jellybean,Android 4.4,KitKat,Android 5.0,iOS,Windows 8,Windows Store,Browser extensions,browser apps,PSP software engineering,TSP software engineering,multiplatform,multiple languages,artist,graphic artist,Graphic Design,Vector,Raster,Photo touchup,photomanipulation,Adobe,Photoshop,Illustrator,CS3,CS4,CS5,CS6,Autodesk,Revit,Maya,3DS Max,Blender,Terragen,Inkscape,GIMP,Ulead,Corel,PhotoImpact,UI,UIX,GUI,TUI,User interface,enthusiast,professional,resume,cv" />
```

which is 75 keywords. All of these reflect what I consider the most important information in the page, especially since some of it (photo touchup, the full list of CS#, etc) is implied in English but probably not inferred by a crawler. Is this too many? Where's the limit?

Additionally, I heard through the grapevine that modern search engines actually ignore keywords in favor of fancy intelligent parsers. If this is true, how to I attach meta information to text on the page like *"CS3,CS4,CS5,CS6"* for *"CS3-6"*, or *"Android,Android 4.0,Ice Cream Sandwich,Android 4.1,Jellybean,Android 4.4,KitKat,Android 5.0"* for *"Android 4.0+"*?

Comment: @JohnConde The other question seems to be one about the actual HTML tag's max length. I know there is no such max length and instead want to know about how the number of keywords affects SEO

Comment: If you read all of the answer you will know everything you need to know about the meta keywords tag

Comment: @JohnConde I read the answer, and it talks about character length, but I'm asking about how the number of keywords affects results. Please, stop disregarding me as a person and actually talk with me instead of dismissing every single thing I do. It makes me feel unwelcome, and that my curiosity is worthless :c

Comment: Straight answer => Any is too many. No known search engine uses Meta Keywords. Nobody can provide any evidence that it's worth wasting time on this particular item. You will get various vague surmises from "SEO Experts" who get money for filling it, but none of them have ever been able to give a straight answer as to what search engine actually uses it. It was dropped long ago as it proved to be a search engine spamming tool. The best use for it is for your competitors to scrape to see what your SEO Marketing focus is, in other words an information leak you might want to close.

Comment: @FiascoLabs then, can you see the second half of my question, asked in the case that meta-keywords mean nothing?

Comment: Then you need to figure out how to present it on the page so that Google doesn't consider it to be [Keyword Stuffing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66358?hl=en) Is it a specification for a product, or just an extraneous list of words in the hope Google presents your content. Maybe you need to figure some sort of tagging system like the Stack Exchanges use.

Comment: @FiascoLabs in order to figure out how to present it so search engines don't consider it Keyword Stuffing, I asked this question. I gave  explicit examples and even a link to the specific page I'm asking this for (John Conde removed that link but you can find it in the edit history). A tagging system where the tags are explicitly shown on-page won't work for my résumé. Instead of commenting your answer, why not actually post an answer to the question?

Comment: Keywords meta-tag is completely ignored for search performance. The question as to which search engines use the data, all of them, but not always for what you expect. There are some clues for search engines such as obvious abuses of keywords meat-tag. Think of this- a mechanism is created that gathers lots of data into a complex database schema. What is easier, rewriting all of your code, or just some of it? Big data people know the answer. Stop thinking in terms of keywords for search performance. It is futile. Instead, think of creating spectacular content that everyone will want to read.

Comment: That's a bit closer to an answer to my question. What qualifies as keyword abuse?